# Distinct not comparable error when binding LINQ query to asp:DataList

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq

I keep getting this error with my below LINQ statement, and I can't figure out why.

> The text data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable.

```
var reportLoad = from dash in
                 (from rl in QVuser.QlikViewPermissions
                  join d in QVuser.QlikViewDashboards on rl.DashboardId equals d.DashboardId
                   where rl.UserId == user && rl.Active == true
                   group rl by new { DashName = d.DashboardName, DashProdLink = d.ProductionLink, DashTestLink = d.TestLink } into g
                   select new { DashName = g.Key.DashName, DashProdLink = g.Key.DashProdLink, DashTestLink = g.Key.DashTestLink })
                       select new
                       {
                            DashName = dash.DashName,
                            DashLink = (whichServer.UseProductionServer ? dash.DashProdLink : dash.DashTestLink)
                       };

this.DataList1.DataSource = reportLoad;
this.DataList1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
var reportLoad =    from d in QVuser.QlikViewDashboards
                    orderby d.DashboardName
                    select new
                    {
                    DashName = d.DashboardName,
                    DashLink =
                             from dd in QVuser.QlikViewDashboards
                              join p in QVuser.QlikViewPermissions on d.DashboardId equals p.DashboardId
                              where p.UserId == user && p.Active == true
                              group dd by dd.DashboardName into g
                              select (whichServer.UseProductionServer ? d.ProductionLink : d.TestLink)
                    };
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `group by` clause.

```
group rl by new { DashName = d.DashboardName, DashProdLink = d.ProductionLink, DashTestLink = d.TestLink } into g
```

The `by` part of `group by` is what determines when each group stops and the next group ends.  Typically a `by` clause will be something simple like `d.DashboardName` which will make groups based on each dashboard.

```
group d by d.DashboardName into g
```

Alternatively if you really want to use a complex object as your group key then create a real object, not an anonymous one, and in your custom object implement `IComparable<>`.

```
group rl by new DashContainer { DashName = d.DashboardName, DashProdLink = d.ProductionLink, DashTestLink = d.TestLink } into g
```

Comment: How do I do my case statement if I just use `group d by d.DashboardName into g`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to try calling ToList() on reportLoad before binding, as in:

```
this.DataList1.DataSource = reportLoad.ToList();
```

If ToList errors, then its an issue in the LINQ query, otherwise, it could be an issue with the data list and how its accessing your data.

HTH.